# Remote kernel running on wsl dies after sleep/hibernation

Tags: windows, remote-access

I'm using a Windows MMA frontend along with a remote WSL (Windows Subsystem for linux) kernel connecting via ssh. Every time I put my laptop to sleep or hibernation for a while, after wake up, the kernel dies.

It could be the sshd alive interval. The default value is 0, but I tried to increase the `ClientAliveInterval` to `1000000`, nothing changed.

Comment: It is unlikely that many users on this forum have a similar setup. This makes the question difficult to answer. You can search for "keepalive", e.g., [ssh keep alive](https://patrickmn.com/aside/how-to-keep-alive-ssh-sessions/). Your best bets for getting good replies is to ask this question at serverfault or superuser SEs.